# How to use TestHiveContext using Spark 2.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to upgrade to Spark 2.2 from Spark 1.6. The existing unit tests are depending on a defined `HiveContext` which was initialised using `TestHiveContext`.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext("local", "sc", conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
val sqlContext = new TestHiveContext(sc)
```

In spark 2.2, `HiveContext` is deprecated and `SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport` is advised to be used. I tried to create a new `SparkSession` using `SparkSession.builder` but I couldn't find a way to initialise a `SparkSession` that uses `TestHiveContext`.

Is it possible to do that or should I change my approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HiveContext and SQLContext has been replaced by SparkSession as stated in the migration guide :

> SparkSession is now the new entry point of Spark that replaces the old
>   SQLContext and
>
> HiveContext. Note that the old SQLContext and HiveContext are kept for
>   backward compatibility. A new catalog interface is accessible from
>   SparkSession - existing API on databases and tables access such as
>   listTables, createExternalTable, dropTempView, cacheTable are moved
>   here.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide-upgrade.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-16-to-20

So you create a Sparksession instance with your test configuration and use it instead of HiveContext